# How to make an image overflow container width instead of warp on 100% height

Tags: css

I'm trying to make an image overflow it's container. I have set the image to 100% height, and it's stretching. I want instead for it to overflow its container's width (I need to then hide that overflow). It's the right most part of the image I'm interested in.

Code coming...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the height of the image to 100% of its container and if nothing is specified about the width, the width should change proportionately i.e. if too wide it should overflow as required. There should be no stretching.

[image]

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 10px red;
}

.container img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/500/300" />
</div>
```

So, is there something else in your CSS that is causing the stretching? e.g. are img widths set somewhere? (Hence, just in case, the width is explicitly set as auto in the snippet).

Comment: This is helpful! I ended up using a background image with the size set to 'cover', but I can see how your solution may have worked. I needed mine to overflow to the left.

Comment: Sorry, I had misinterpreted on the left right. You’d need to position the img right 0. Glad you found a way forward. Background image is great if it does what you want in terms of setting the container dimensions.

Comment: Changing the position from static eliminates the height of the container, though. That's one problem I encountered. I wonder if you could switch the text flow from left-to-right to right-to-left? Anyways, something to return to perhaps someday...